# Angular 2 mysteriously modifies all sub-nested similar object within an object with the same value

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

As can be seen in the example at https://plnkr.co/edit/YyTPVQ?p=preview (Once loaded the app click on any of the names on  the left bar)

If I modify any user's scale it also modifies the other user too.

Don't ask me why but, I somehow managed to fix it by deleting all .map and .js files, committed the fix to git, woke up this morning and now it doesn't work AGAIN (YES is a miraculous as it sounds!) https://github.com/thurft/appraisal

**My problem is as follows** the `employees.component.ts` handles the logic of `employees.component.html`

When I rate a question it modifies the same question of **all** `this.employee` **instead of only doing it for** `this.selectedEmployee`. This would be triggered `updateQuestionRequest(question)` and there is a `console.log(this.employees)` to show the Objects being modified.

In no way I modify  `this.employees` array, so Angular somehow knows that it needs to modify the object in the array. But it also modifies all objects in that array that have the same question.

**The question/problem is:** How can I save the selectedEmployee rated question in the selectedEmployee OBJ instead of the value being saved across all employees OBJ?

I can't tell if is a bug on Angular or is a problem in my code, as sometimes it work, sometimes it doesn't and there is no consistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of Chrome not implmenenting yet the `Object.assign` the work around is to create a new json file to force the create of a new object `employee[i].technicalQuestions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(TECHNICALQUESTIONS));`

Answer (score 1):

You have to clone `TECHNICALQUESTIONS` otherwise all employees will share the same reference:

```
employee[i].technicalQuestions = TECHNICALQUESTIONS.map(_=>{return Object.assign({}, _)};);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But if I do that i get the following error `EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. in [selectedEmployee.technicalQuestions in EmployeesComponent@18:34]`

Comment: your amended answer now throws `EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: i've tried your sample and it works, changes have to be applied to [line 15](https://github.com/thurft/appraisal/blob/master/app/services/employee.service.ts#L15) of `EmployeeService`

Comment: I did tried it. but it get the same error :-/ . I just kept on googling and you know what works.... `employee[i].technicalQuestions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(TECHNICALQUESTIONS));` that somehow creates a new obj

Comment: i guess it is because i use firefox which is the only browser that implements Object.assign. I get used to polyfills so just did not pay attention. Old JSON trick did it, good.